# How do I shrink div height to fit an image

Tags: html, css, flash

[problem](http://postimg.org/image/43er6m3bv/)

I want my div to shrink in line with a flash image when the browser is resized but it won't.
The margins appear to get larger.

```
.slider {
background-color:#666;
max-height: 100%;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
}

<div class="slider">
    <embed src="images/slider2/slider2.swf" width="100%"></embed>
</div>
```

My other divs, menu for example shrink fine so I assume it's something to do with the flash??

Many thanks... probably a stupid question!

Are there any more suggestions please? If I insert an image instead of the flash, it's fine. So the problem must be related to how the browser treats flash or that I am failing to do whatever is necessary to allow for it. Thanks

Comment: Where is you `slider2.swf` in the image that you added in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slider {
    float:left;
    background-color:#666;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
        <embed src="images/slider2/slider2.swf" width="100%"></embed>
    </div>
```

Does it work now ?
Please do not forget to tick on the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I happily would click, but unfortunately it doesn't work so I can't! It has no effect I can see.

Comment: NO. That creates a left menu bar.

Comment: Try float:inherit; or float:none; in css

Comment: thanks for trying but that isn't working. I've added a link to an image of the problem in the initial message. This is what happens when I resize the browser. [Problem]

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: I don't have chrome and using a different browser doesn't solve the problem, if it works, for those not using chrome.